# Does the F-35B use its articulating rear jet nozzle for thrust vectoring?

Tags: f-35, thrust-vectoring

Does the F-35B use its articulating rear jet nozzle for thrust vectoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hovering or STOL/STOVL/VTOL flight yes it can vector its thrust but the system is not operable during conventional flight modes.  No version of the F-135 is publicly known to be capable of this.  Unlike the Harrier, F-35Bs cannot use the vertical lift system in the conventional flight regime.